# Laravel Intermediate relations data error

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Here is my **RecentViewController** file code:

```
$contents = RecentView::where('user_id', $loggedUser)
                        ->with('posts')
                        ->with('profile')
                        ->paginate(12)->toArray();
```

and my **RecentView** model code is as follows:

```
public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\FeedPost', 'id', 'post_id');
    }

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Profile', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

the data i receive after running this code shows logged in users details instead of posts users detaisl. how can i change retreiving posts users data instead of logged users data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying to get the user of the post
In order to get posts users detail you need to move profile relation into `Post` model. I hope there's a `user_id` in posts table. then get profile relationship of post model with dot notation as follows

```php
$contents = RecentView::where('user_id', $loggedUser)
                        ->with('posts.profile')
                        ->paginate(12)->toArray();
```

Comment: Thankyou for the input, will try and let u know if it works.

Comment: Thankyou @ravisha. U saved my day.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.